# Javascript value from JSONP and PHP value differ when requesting same thing?

Tags: javascript, php

When I execute the following, I get from the PHP this:

```
text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8gzip,deflate,sdchen-US,en;q=0.8,el;q=0.6,de;q=0.4
```

but the `alert(hello)` from the response of the php file, is different, it is

```
*/*gzip,deflate,sdchen-US,en
```

Why is this difference? I need to get through JavaScript the same PHP value

**This is the script**

```
<script>

function requestServerCall(url) {
    var head = document.head;
    var script = document.createElement("script");

script.setAttribute("src", url);
head.appendChild(script);
head.removeChild(script);
}


function httpAcceptResponse(data) {
 var hello = data.token;
 alert(hello);
    }

function getHTTP() {
  requestServerCall("http://www.domain.com/httpaccept.php?callback=httpAcceptResponse");
}


getHTTP();

</script>
```

**httpAccept.php file**

```
<?php
    $callback = $_GET["callback"];
    $headers = $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT'].$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'].$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'];
    $jsonResponse = "{\"token\":\"" . $headers. "\"}";
    echo $callback . "(" . $jsonResponse . ")";
?>
```

Comment: Sure are missing a bunch of code that would be helpful to diagnose this.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I have updated now my question with more code, thank you.

Comment: Don't build your JSON response manually in PHP.  Use `json_encode()`.

Comment: @MikeBrant Can you guide me how please?

Comment: It may be a problem with how you generate the response. Use `$jsonResponse = json_encode(array('token' => $header));` to create the object literal instead. The JSON will be a valid object literal if evaluated as JS in this context.

Comment: And in general, if you are wondering how a function works, have a look at its documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: @FelixKling Thank you but I got a null value after doing this

Comment: @Fataoulas: You might have overlooked my typo. I used `$header` instead of `$headers`.

Comment: @FelixKling didn't work, i get the same result

Answer (score 1):

The issue behind this is that browsers don't seem to provide `Accept` and `Accept-Encoding` fields in a HTTP request for a script. (At least Chrome does not.)

At least for `Accept` this somewhat makes sense because when requesting a JavaScript file you don't really need to provide the `Accept` field - you expect the requested file to be a JavaScript file after all. However, I don't understand the lack of `Accept-Encoding` either.

To solve this you might want to perform a AJAX request that first gets the script code and then puts it into the content of a newly created `<script>` tag. So don't use `src` but use the tag's content. This should work because AJAX HTTP requests should also contain the `Accept` and `Accept-Encoding` fields.